# Error in generating colored cmy qr image

Tags: python, image, opencv, qr-code

I have to generate 3 QR images with background color cyan, magenta and yellow and merge them to generate CMY colored QR as shown in image 1. Now after generating images, to merge them by using cv2.merge,converting these into gray image and then merging operation gives me image 2 instead of image 1 (Ignore the color of finder patterns) I am using Python 2.7, Open CV 3.0. Unable to figure out what I am doing wrong. Please help me to get out of this. Thanks in advance.

[image: Snapshot1]

[image: Snapshot2]

Code I am using is given below:

```
import pyqrcode
import cv2
bigcode = pyqrcode.create('When I say it is you', error='L', version=2,mode='binary')
bigcode.png('new1.png', scale=6, module_color=[0, 0, 0], background = [0xff,0xff,0])
bigcode1 = pyqrcode.create('peace that triumphant over war ', error='L', version=2, mode='binary')
bigcode1.png('new2.png', scale=6, module_color=[0, 0, 0], background = [0xff,0,0xff])
bigcode2 = pyqrcode.create('Love that conquers hate ', error='L', version=2, mode='binary')
bigcode2.png('new3.png', scale=6, module_color=[0, 0, 0], background = [0,0xff,0xff])
bigcode.show()
b = bigcode1.show()
c = bigcode2.show()
img1 = cv2.imread('C:/New folder (2)/new1.png')
img2 = cv2.imread('C:/New folder (2)/new2.png')
img3 = cv2.imread('C:/New folder (2)/new3.png')
gray_img1 = cv2.cvtColor(img1, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
cv2.imshow('k1',gray_img1)         
gray_img2 = cv2.cvtColor(img2, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

gray_img3 = cv2.cvtColor(img3, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

k = cv2.merge([gray_img1,gray_img2,gray_img3])

cv2.imshow('k',k)
cv2.imwrite('k.png',k)

cv2.waitKey(0)
```

Comment: I don't know OpenCV very well, but you have loaded three grayscale images and told it to make them a 3-channel image. I would imagine it is going to assume that the 3 channels you have provided are red, green and blue, rather than cyan, magenta and yellow. I guess you must tell OpenCV that is the case and convert to RGB colorspace.

Comment: @mark: thanks for answering... since generated images are 3- channel image so in order to use cv2.merge I am coverting these to grayscale . Is there any way other than cv2.merge to merge those initially generated images??

Comment: And I want final result in cmy not in rgb colorspace...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of generating c,m,y,k colored QR, try to convert rgb in cmyk colorspace. this would help in generating correct result.

Answer (score 1):

Though the owner have got the answer, would like to share what been suggested by @Priya. Tried to implement in below steps, do let me know if it were wrong, thanks.

1) Create 3 barcode and colored with R, G, B as the background respectively.
2) Take R, G, B channels from the generated barcode and merge together.
3) Convert the RGB barcode to CMYK colorspace.

```
import pyqrcode
import cv2
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image

bigcode_r = pyqrcode.create('This is red', error='L', version=2,mode='binary')
bigcode_r.png('bigcode_r.png', scale=12, module_color=[0, 0, 0], background = [0xff,0,0])

bigcode_g = pyqrcode.create('This is green', error='L', version=2, mode='binary')
bigcode_g.png('bigcode_g.png', scale=12, module_color=[0, 0, 0], background = [0,0xff,0])

bigcode_b = pyqrcode.create('This is blue', error='L', version=2, mode='binary')
bigcode_b.png('bigcode_b.png', scale=12, module_color=[0, 0, 0], background = [0,0,0xff])

img_r = cv2.imread('bigcode_r.png')
img_g = cv2.imread('bigcode_g.png')
img_b = cv2.imread('bigcode_b.png')

merge_rgb = cv2.merge((img_b[:,:,0], img_g[:,:,1], img_r[:,:,2]))
#print(k.shape)
cv2.imshow('merge_rgb',merge_rgb)
cv2.imwrite('merge_rgb.jpg', merge_rgb)

#img_str = cv2.imencode('.jpg', merge_rgb)[1].tostring()
#imgpil = Image.open(BytesIO(img_str))

imgpil = Image.open('merge_rgb.jpg')
cmyk_image = imgpil.convert('CMYK')
cmyk_image.save('cmyk_image.jpg')

cmyk_image = cv2.imread('cmyk_image.jpg')
cv2.imshow('cmyk_image',cmyk_image)

cv2.waitKey(0)
```

[Generated barcode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ivkyZ.png)

Comment: It is an answer with implementation. @Priya suggestion is to convert final rgb image to cmyk image if i got it correctly. Apart from this, to generate the rgb image, i think we should take r, g, b channel from the corresponding barcode image and merge them instead of convert barcode images to gray scale and merge.